# Manifolds with smooth structure

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

One of the remark in my lecture notes said:

> In dimension $\leq 3$, every topological manifold has a unique smooth structure (up to diffeomorphism.)

I don't quite understand what is a structure in a manifold. Can you give me some examples, say what is a smooth structure of $S^2=$ surface of unit sphere in $  \mathbb{R^3}$

Comment: Are you sure your lecture notes don't describe what a smooth structure is prior to this statement? It seems out of place otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Smooth structure on a manifold is an equivalence class of $C^\infty$-atlases if I recall correctly.

Comment: Your statement can be interpreted as: If $M_1$, $M_2$ are two smooth manifold of dimension $\le 3$ so that $M_1$ and $M_2$ are homeomorphic as topological space. Then they are diffeomorphic. This is not true when the dimension is $\ge 4$. (I guess the easiest example was given by Milnor in dimension 7, where he constructed some $S^7$ with different smooth structures)

Comment: I'm not sure how this statement can be correct.  In the 1-dimensional case the only connected manifolds are homeomorphic to the circle $S^1$ or $\mathbb{R}$.  Wouldn't the graph of a triangle wave-form still be a 1-dimensional topological manifold with no smooth structure?  Can someone please elucidate me on this fact?

Comment: @Mnifldz: Your 1 dimensional toplogical manifold is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, thus CAN be given a smooth structure (that of $\mathbb R$). The statement is that That smooth structure is the only one you can put on it. If I understand correctly, it is also true that all topological manifold of dimension $\le 3$ can be given a smooth structure (someone correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: At least according to wikipedia, all these are not true in dimension 4. (there is topo. manifold with no smooth structure, and smooth structure on a topological manifold is not unique)

Comment: @John If I understand correctly, we can define the smooth structure on the graph of triangular wave form by defining a smooth structure on $\mathbb R$ and mapping the atlases via the homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and the wave form?  How does this preserve the smooth structure of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: If $ f: W\to \mathbb R$ is a homeomorphism, then we can define a smooth structure on $W$, so that $f$ is diffeomorphic ($W$ is your wave). @Mnifldz